# pcap_sendqueue_transmit equivalent for linux

Tags: libpcap

I am trying to do high speed packet sending on Linux using libpcap (~100mbps but >100k packets/second).  The limitation appears to be (although I am not sure) the number of calls to pcap_send.

Winpcap has pcap_sendqueue_transmit, which allows multiple packets to be sent at once.  I do not believe that libpcap has this function.

That being said, AFAIK, libpcap uses PF_PACKET https://stackoverflow.com/a/22996556/4381435.  And packet mmap can peform this single system call send http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt?id=HEAD

So, is there some libpcap method of doing this that I can't find?

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there some libpcap method of doing this that I can't find?

No.  You'd have to directly do the ring-buffer send yourself.